# How can I make the SOQL return the "response"?

Tags: soql, workbench

I'm a newbie.

I have a custom object "transaction__c" and looking in the workbench I have many fields, but doens't show the field "response_c"

[image: list of fields in workbench]

, but in the object have him
[image: image of field in the object]

With this I made a query:

SELECT Response__c,  name FROM Transaction__c where name ='test';

I execute the query and the return is:
[image: return of the query is: No such column 'Response__c' on entity 'ServiceTransaction__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.]

Comment: 1. Can you confirm that the field actually exists on the object? In Salesforce go to Setup > Object Manager > find your object > in the 'Fields & Relationships" for the object verify that the field is there. 2. If the field really exists, check if your user's profile has access to that field.

Comment: Also double-check that you have connected workbench to the same org that you used to inspect the object model.

Comment: Your OP says `Transaction__c` yet error message is about `ServiceTransaction__c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the FLS for that field.

Setup --> Object Manager --> transition__c --> response__c --> Set Field-Level Security

Make sure that field is Visible to your profile

Comment: Thanks guy, u r the best.